# Is there some connection between these two methods counting isomorphic irreducible submodules for a decomposition of regular $A$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, semi-simple-rings, representation-of-algebras

Let $A$ be a semisimple algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Given a decomposition $A^{\circ} = \oplus W_i$ of the regular $A$-module $A^{\circ}$ and an irreducible $A$-submodule $M$, I have seen two ways to calculate the number $n_M(A^{\circ})$ of $W_i$ which is isomorphic to $M$. Now I wonder whether there is some connection between these two methods, can anyone please help?

One way is from Issacs' *Character Theory of Finite Groups*, but also quite common among other textbooks. One decomposes $A^{\circ}$ first into simple algebras $M(A)$ (where $M(A) = \oplus \{W_i: W_i \cong M\}$ denotes the $M$-homogeneous direct summand). For every $x \in A$, we have a natural homomorphism $x_M: M \to M, v \mapsto vx$. This induces an algebra homomorphism $\theta: A \rightarrow \operatorname{End}(M),\, x \mapsto x_M$. Denote its image by $A_M$, one can show $M(A) \cong A_M$. Finally one uses *Double Centralizer Theorem* to claim that $A_M = \operatorname{End}(M)$, and it follows immediately that $\dim A_M = (\dim M)^2$. Thus $n_M(A^{\circ}) = \frac{\dim A_M}{\dim M} = \dim M$.

The *Double Centralizer Theorem* is as follows, where $\operatorname{E}_A(M) = \operatorname{Hom}_A(M, M)$ is the centralizer of $A_M$ in $\operatorname{End}(M)$.

> **Theorem (Double Centralizer)**: Let $A$ be a semisimple algebra and let $M$ be an irreducible $A$-algebra. Let $D=E_A(M)$. Let $E_D(M)=A_M$.

An alternative way of doing this is from James & Liebeck, *Representations and Characters of Groups*, which is by counting the dimension of $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M)$ in two ways. The first way uses $\dim(\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M)) = \Sigma_i \dim(\operatorname{Hom}_A(W_i,M))$. Since $\dim(\operatorname{Hom}_A(W_i,M))$ equals $1$ if $W_i \cong M$, and $0$ if $W_i \not\cong M$, one knows $\dim(\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M)) = n_M(A).$ The second way implies $\dim(\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M)) = \dim M$. Equalizing the two ways above one gets $n_M(A) = \dim M$.

I think there is some connections between these two ways for the following reasons. Both methods use the space of algebra homomorphisms between modules. Furthermore, the second way constructs
a module homomorphism $\phi_v: A^{\circ} \to M, x \mapsto vx, v \in M$, and this homomorphism can also be used in several steps of the first method. I guess there may be some connection between this homomorphism $\phi_v$ and the other homomorphism $\theta$ contructed in the first method, because these two are similar in form, where both are constructed by letting $A$ act on $M$, and because if one views $M$ as a subalgebra of $A$, $x_v$ also becomes an algebra homomorpism. But I am not sure whether there is such connection, and what exactly the connection is. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.